# Generalization of Dirichlet's test

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) states:
If $\left\{a_{k}\right\},\left\{b_{k}\right\}$ are two sequences in real numbers then $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k}$ converges if the three following conditions hold:

- $a_{k+1}\le a_{k}$
- $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k =0$
- $\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k}\right|\le M$ for positive real number $M$ and $n \in \mathbb N^{+}$

I tried to generalize the test to "if $\left\{a_{k}\right\}$ is monotonic" instead of "monotone decreasing".

For simplicity I start the lower limit of the series with $1$.

Proof:

Define $S_{n}\ :=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k}$ and observe that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}b_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}\left(S_{k}-S_{k-1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}S_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}S_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)+a_{n+1}S_{n}$$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n+1}S_{n}=0$
Since $S_{n}$ is bounded and by the assumption $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{n}=0$, also:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|S_{k}\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}M\left|\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)\right|=M\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)\right|$$

Either $\left\{a_{k}\right\}$ is monotone increasing or monotone decreasing, so the RHS is either $-M\left(a_{1}-a_{n+1}\right)$ or $M\left(a_{1}-a_{n+1}\right)$ respectively, so $M\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)\right| \to -Ma_{1}$ or $M\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)\right| \to Ma_{1}$ as $n \to \infty$.

This fact follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|S_{k}\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)\right|$ converges, and so does $\sum_{k=1}^{n}S_{k}\left(a_{k}-a_{k+1}\right)$, hence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{k}b_{k}$ converges.

Moreover we see that Dirichlet's test is a generalization of Alternating series test, since $\left\{a_{k}\right\}$ is monotonic and $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|b_{n}\right|\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left|\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}\right|\le1$, also $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_k =0$.

Can someone check the validity of my proof?

---

Note: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) says:

[image]

So $\left|a_{n}\right|\le\left|a_{n+1}\right|$ then if $a_{n+1}\ge0$ we have:$-a_{n+1}\le a_{n}\le a_{n+1}$ which is an increasing sequence, if $a_{n+1}<0$ then $a_{n+1}\le a_{n}\le-a_{n+1}$ which is a decreasing sequence, so having a monotonic sequence $\left\{a_{k}\right\}$ implies such series converges and this coincides with the theorem I proved .

Comment: What if you just apply Dirichlet's test with $-a_n$ in place of $a_n$ when your sequence is increasing?

Comment: your proof looks fine.But simpler proof is what @Gary has suggested is to just use your previous theorem

Comment: @viru, yes it seems that way is simpler, but I really don't get that, can you please explain how we can use Gary's suggestion?

Comment: If $a_k$ is increasing and its limit is $0$ then the sequence $-a_k$ is decresing and tends to $0$. Thus by Dirichlet's test, $\sum {( - a_k )b_k }$ converges. But this just means that $ - \sum {a_k b_k }$ and hence $\sum {a_k b_k }$ converges. That is what we wanted to show.

Comment: @Gary, really thanks, so we can change the first condition to "if $\left\{a_{k}\right\}$ is monotonic"

Comment: @user715522 Yes.